# react native DeviceEventEmitter unsubscribe from event

Tags: javascript, react-native, events, event-handling

I'm using `DeviceEventEmitter` to handle events of a favorite method, to which is subscribed in the constructor:

```
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener("FavoriteClick", async (e) => 
{
    // do something
})
```

This event listener stays active whenever the components unmounts (permenantly). What do I have to call to unsub? I've tried storing the event as a variable and calling `listener.removeCurrentListener()` in the `componentWillUnmount()` [like the (limited) documentation states](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js), if I understand that correctly, but `removeCurrentListener()` is not a method.

Comment: addListener returns an EmitterSubscription, which has the inherent method ".remove()". Therefore, your code should look like this: 


const favoriteClickSub = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener("FavoriteClick", (e) => {});

favoriteClickSub.remove();

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`DeviceEventEmitter` is [deprecated](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1490ab12ef156bf3201882eeabfcac18a1210352/Libraries/EventEmitter/RCTNativeAppEventEmitter.js#L15), you should use `NativeEventEmitter` instead.

[Example](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios) :

```
import { NativeEventEmitter, NativeModules } from 'react-native';

const { CalendarManager } = NativeModules;

const calendarManagerEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(CalendarManager);

const subscription = calendarManagerEmitter.addListener(
  'EventReminder',
  (reminder) => console.log(reminder.name)
);

...

// Don't forget to unsubscribe, typically in componentWillUnmount
subscription.remove();
```

Comment: what about native part? can I still use `reactContext.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter::class.java).emit(....)` on Android native side?