# How to unsubscribe from a DeviceEventEmitter eventListener?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, deviceeventemitter

I have the following `useEffect` hook that adds an event listener if `isAuthenticated` is true:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
        Doorman.guard(onSessionExpiration);
    }
}, [isAuthenticated, onSessionExpiration]);
```

The problem is that when the user logs out, the `Doorman.guard(onSessionExpiration)` is not unregistered which causes some problems, which is why I'm trying to figure out how to unsubscribe.

The guard function looks like this:

```
import { DeviceEventEmitter } from 'react-native';

export const Doorman = {
    guard(fn: () => void) {
        return DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('UNAUTHORIZED', fn);
    }
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react native DeviceEventEmitter unsubscribe from event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58285364/react-native-deviceeventemitter-unsubscribe-from-event)

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv No because I have to use DeviceEventEmitter and the answer in the question you've supplied uses NativeEventEmitter.

Comment: There's a comment there answering your question. Yours is still an exact duplicate of that one.